# Large data migration workflow

Tags: gui-design, data, workflow

Can anyone suggest the best way to represent this workflow for managing a large data migration which requires a manual FTP stage on the customer end? I am thinking a wizard to take us up to the FTP stage then a table with an updating status.

The steps are:

1. We create a migration job in our admin UI capturing job name, size and some other details
2. The customer is then instructed via email to start uploading their zipped data using FTP details that we provide.
3. The customer informs us that they are finished uploading the data
4. We click a button to start the pre-processing/indexing of the data stage so that it can be verified. Once complete we send a verification link to the customer which takes them to a search UI allowing them to run searches on the indexed data to verify it is correct.
5. The customer clicks a 'I verify this data is correct' link from the search UI
6. We then manually start the import job by clicking a button in the
   admin UI
7. The import job then takes a couple of hours to complete depending on the amount of data to import
8. Once complete we are able to preview a report of all the files and errors of the import

What I don't like are all the manual steps involved in this current workflow. Having to wait until certain manual actions are finished and then having to click buttons to proceed. I worry that people will be clicking buttons before they are ready to be clicked. If anyone can suggest a good mechanism for this it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Although not a UX solution, have a look at CuteFTP which has a powerful scripting engine, which can interface to and from apps, which may allow you to automate a lot of this https://www.globalscape.com/cuteftp